# Subtracting angles of complex valued matrix

Tags: python

Let's say I have two complex images `Z_1` and `Z_2`. I want to make a relative-phase map of the second image with respect to the first. This means:

`Z_2_relative = Z_2 * np.exp(-1j * np.angle(Z_1))`

This creates a new complex valued matrix where the complex-phase should now be given by

`np.angle(Z_2_relative) == np.angle(Z_2) - np.angle(Z_1)`

But according to python these two are not equal. I bet it has something to do with the `np.angle` function.. but I cant pinpoint it, or know how to fix it...

PS: Sorry, cant make a reproducible piece of code atm. Can do it later today

Comment: just a guess, but could it be that np.angle(Z_2) - np.angle(Z_1) can become larger than 2pi and np.angle(Z_2_relative) can not ?

Comment: yeah, Indeed that is the whole problem.. I just figured it out myself as well.... gah, what a stupid mistake

Answer (score 0):

Bah.. stupid question. Sorry for anyone that read it. If you do module `2pi`, then everything is the same